# Web scraping constantly updating data in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm trying to make this small program that scrapes the social blade website `https://socialblade.com/youtube/user/pewdiepie/realtime` for the sub count.
The data on the site is constantly being updated, how would i make this work so i get the number of subscribers each second or so?

Answer (score 0):

You can run your code in a loop and just sleep between calls.

```
import time

while some_true_condition:
    scrape()
    time.sleep(10)
```

The `10` refers to 10 seconds, which is a more reasonable approach. You might get banned if you query every second.